# Used camera's grip base has jutting rubber, is this serious?

Tags: nikon, equipment-damage, used-equipment, nikon-d7100

I've recently upgraded to a bigger dslr (nikon d7100), which I got used.

Never having owned a bigger dslr, I would like to know if the jutting part of the hand-grip base is some sort of damage or just wear?

Attached is an image of 'new' base for comparison of the jutting part.

[image: front]
[image: base]
[image: New]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't damage, it's the rubber flap that covers the hole where the cord for an external power source enters the camera.  You'll find an illustration of how it works on page 311 of the [owner's manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/Wt74B00WmPdp01GF7sU080xUqy56/D7100_(En)03.pdf).

[image: page 311]

That one just looks like it isn't properly seated and should pop easily back into place.